# Sourcetree shows develop and master in origin, but bitbucket shows only master and develop merged, how to fix it?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-flow

I am trying to use gitflow with bitbucket and sourcetree, could anybody tell me what is the best? to keep the develop and releases branches/tags always separated of the master or always merge it?

I wanted to have them separated, but when I make a push on bitbucket's branch section there is only a master and at the merged sections are the others, what is the best way to do it? and how can I use the best way of gitflow using sourcetree?

Thanks.

EDIT.

Here are the screenshots.

Locally is like this
[image]

and at bitbucket is like this: (theactive shows only master and develop is only at merged)

[image]

Is this correct? I really dont know when I should see the merged branches and where I should not.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're asking. Could you add a screenshot of the commit graph, or a diagram showing it?

Comment: hello, Ive updated it, could you please take a look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A branch is considered "merged into `master`" if its head is *reachable* from `master`.

*Reachable* means that if you start from `master` and follow each commit backwards through its ancestry at some point you find the commit you're looking for.

For example:

```
              G [master]
             /
A---B---C---D   [branch-a]
     \
      E---F     [branch-b]
```

Here, `branch-a` is reachable from `master`. Start at `master`'s head (commit `G`) and go backwards to `D`, which is the head of `branch-a`.

In contrast, `branch-b` is *not* reachable from `master`. If you trace backwards from `master` you get `G`, `D`, `C`, `B`, `A`. `branch-b`'s head (commit `F`) is not found.

Since you currently only have one commit with both `develop` and `master` pointing at it, `develop` is necessarily reachable from `master` and is therefore "merged".

Once you start adding commits to `develop` that aren't yet in `master`, `develop` will no longer show up as "merged".

**Edit:**

Here is a common scenario with Git Flow. This is simplified; I'm not showing feature or release branches.

```
A           [master]
 \
  B---C---D [develop]
```

Here you're working on `develop`, which contains three commits `B`, `C` and `D` which are unreachable from `master`. `develop` is *not* merged.

Now you decide to do a release, resulting in something like

```
A-----------E [master]
 \         /
  B---C---D   [develop]
```

`develop` is now merged into `master`, since we can reach `develop` (at commit `D`) from `master` (at commit `E`).

Now you start working again...

```
A-----------E   [master]
 \         /
  B---C---D---F [develop]
```

...and `develop` is no longer merged.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! so, basically, if I am using gitflow (or any other method) I am going to have "master" only? and the other branches will be shown as merged?

Comment: @jpganz18, no. It depends what part of the workflow you're on. I've added another example that will hopefully be helpful.

Comment: Thank you @Chris. Your explanation is a welcomed find!